# Hosting plan Specifications preference to create an Online Image Editor

Tags: web-hosting

I intent to create an Online image editor like http://pixlr.com/editor. I want to use ASP.NET as the P-language and so prefer windows hosting.What should i look for like Bandwidth,Space,Database etc.I wonder how many concurrent users can use the site(with/without db connection)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a dedicated or VPS and upgrade as you see fit, start small and expand. The real queestion is how many people will use it, as thats what governs the resources